# How to extract specific content, like name or DOB, from a document using NLP and python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

I want to extract very specific content like name, address and dob from a document (say for example, a resume). Assuming I have 1000 of such documents, I want to automate it using machine learning and natural language processing. And preferably python.
How can I do that? or Where do I start?

Update: I am aware of NER but I am looking to extract very specific information from a document which can be loaded into an excel or something.

Example: From a project report, I would like to extract the topic, team member names and tenure of the project.

Comment: I'd start with figuring out which piece of information is easiest to identify, (e.g. the ZIP code might be easy to pick out since 5-digit numbers are otherwise rare) and search backwards/forwards from there with a regular expression. I would suggest that in a semi-structured document like a resume, NLP is probably overkill.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: @MoralesBatovski : i understand, but the problem is I am not sure what to look for and need a starting point.

Comment: @machineyearning: i could use regular expressions for fixed stuff, but what if i want to pick up father's name of a candidate from the resume or any document

Comment: This is subject to the data that you are using.Well if want to perform all those things its better to convert the doc to excel format and use SQL/R, it will require manual work and there is no fixed way to automate such a thing. Especially when peoples resumes are of different formats. Otherwise, if you insist on reading from the doc file. **1.** Find patterns in the resume **2.** Apply regex **3.** Profit??

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you are looking for, is what is known in NLP as Named Entity recognition (NER).

Actually, an Entity can be the a person name, a place name a campany name etc..

You can look at this stackOverFlow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37853877/python-frameworks-for-nlp/37863761#37863761) for more information.

Comment: I know about NER but that is not what I am looking for. NER pulls generic fields like person, orgs and places. But I want to extract specific information of my choice, then load it into a excel.